# Tensorflow model detecting wrong objects?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow. I trained a model with 900 images of shoes. I put 20%(180 images) into test folder and 80%(720 images) into train folder. But after training, my trained model is detecting other objects also as shoes. Attached below is the screen shot of the prediction by my model.

**Question1:**  Can anyone can help me please, where am i going wrong?

I am training this model on MAC Machine, and using faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28 model to train my model.

I follow the link to train model:
https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10/tree/d1c5b59803543e48362c27c48d704d4b0d92d135

**Question 2:** And more thing when i run this model on webcam it is very slow why?

Thanks in advance...

**Screenshots**

[Please check this Image detecting wrong object as shoe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVHKX.png)

[Please check this image detecting shoe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXsLp.png)

Comment: it seems your model can find any object in the image but label them wrongly. It finds the dogs very well but labels them as 'shoe'. Maybe you should check somewhere in your code to ignore any class rather than 'shoe'.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot dear, but i trained my model only for shoes, why it detecting dogs, what may be the cause?